# How to derivate the volume of a potato?

Tags: summation, area, volume

In a project, we are asked to derivate the volume of a potato. In my mind, I thought of using summation, like cutting the potato into slices. So I'd calculate the area of the slice and multiply it by the width and sum all slices I cut together to get a complete, estimated Volume. However, should the width of the slices have the same length or is it completely ok if I use different lengths for the width?

Comment: Couldn't you do the same as Arkimedes? Put the potato in some water and measure the displacement?

Comment: I love potatoes. But yes, Archimedean water displacement sounds like a good idea

Comment: That's what I tried. However, it's prohibited to use such a method. We are assigned to use a mathematical method, not a scientific, @CoveredInChocolate

Comment: Like putting the potato in water is not allowed. @Riemann'sPointyNose

Comment: You need to define what an ideal potato is ? Is it a cylinder with two spherical ends, is it an ovoid, an ellipse of revolution, etc... Then we can calculate the theoretical volume. "*It is a mistake to think you can solve any major problems just with potatoes ©D.Adams*"

Comment: That seems odd to me, I'm not sure how you can Mathematically calculate the volume of it without resorting to using some scientific method. "Potato" isn't a standardised geometrical object, every potato is going to have unique bumps etc. Unless they want to to approximate it as a sphere?

Comment: Who knows, maybe they want you to discuss that as part of your project. "Standardising the potato"

Comment: It's more of an approximation method, @Riemann'sPointyNose

Comment: You could view the potato as a solid of revolution. You can model the curve you'd rotate around an axis, say the $x$-axis, using a polynomial regression.

Comment: I see. As @zwim and I said, unless you can use a scientific method, you will have to choose what an "ideal" potato is to standardise it as a geometrical object. To explain further what I mean, we can calculate the volume of a theoretical sphere, but cannot theoretically calculate the volume of a football **without approximating the football as a sphere** (since footballs are not actually perfect spheres). This is probably the issue your paper wants you to discuss; how will you approximate the potato theoretically? As a sphere? 3D ovalish shape?

Comment: A derivate is something derived. You want to derive the volume of the potato.

Comment: You are probably being asked to derive the volume of an ellipsoid.

Comment: Yes, @John Douma. I thought of approximating for example, by cutting the potato into finite slices, calculating the area of each slide, whereby the slice is identical to an oval shape, and multiplying by width, where we get the volume for one slice. After that we add all slices together and get an estimated Volume. Someway somewhat...

Comment: If you are using single variable calculus you can use a volume of revolution.